# code for multiplication in Prolog doesn't work

Tags: prolog

This is my attempt for creating the multiplication operator in Prolog.

```
times1(X,Y,Z) :- Z=X*Y.
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know why. Could anyone recognize the problem ?

```
times1(0,Y,0):-!.
times1(X,0,0):-!.
times1(X,Y,Z):- X<0,Y<0,!, times1(-X,-Y,Z).
times1(X,Y,Z):- X>0,!,times1(X-1,Y,Z1),Z is Z1+Y.
times1(X,Y,Z):- X<0,Y>0,times1(Y,X,Z).
```

Second try:

```
times1(0,ֹ_,0):-!. 
times1(_,0,0):-!.  
times1(X,Y,Z):- X<0,Y=\=0,X1 is -X, times1(X1,Y,Z1), Z is -Z1.
times1(X,Y,Z):- X>0,Y=\=0, X2 is X-1, times1(X2,Y,Z1),Z is Z1+Y.
```

still doesn't work...

Comment: I tried your new solution and it works for me (although `iS` should be `is`). Can you explain what you mean by *still doesn't work...*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first solution:

```
times1(X,Y,Z) :- Z=X*Y.
```

The problem is the use of unification instead of expression evaluation. Use `is/2` for expression evaluation:

```
times1(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X*Y.
```

In the second solution:

```
times1(0,Y,0):-!.
times1(X,0,0):-!.
times1(X,Y,Z):- X<0,Y<0,!, times1(-X,-Y,Z).
times1(X,Y,Z):- X>0,!,times1(X-1,Y,Z1),Z is Z1+Y.
times1(X,Y,Z):- X<0,Y>0,times1(Y,X,Z).
```

In the expression `times1(X-1,Y,Z1)` Prolog will not evaluate `X-1` before using it as the argument to the recursive call. You need to do this explicitly: `X1 is X-1, times1(X1,Y,Z1)`.

Also, you don't need so many cuts. Since you are already, for example, checking the `X` and `Y` condition for `0` in the other predicate clauses, the base cases can be just:

```
times1(0, _, 0).  % 0 times anything is 0
times1(_, 0, 0).  % Anything times 0 is 0
```

You don't need to check both `X` and `Y` for negative because `X*Y`, if `Y` is negative, can be just `X` number of the `Y` values added together anyway, regardless of the sign of `Y`. And then, after negating `X` to get a result, you still need to negate the final sum (to compensate for the negated `X`):

```
times1(X, Y, Z) :- X < 0, Y =\= 0, times1(-X, Y, Z1), Z is -Z1.
times1(X, Y, Z) :- X > 0, Y =\= 0, X1 is X-1, times1(X1, Y, Z1), Z is Z1+Y.
```

These really are almost just like what you have, except that your `Y < 0` and `Y > 0` cases have been consolidated into one with `Y =\= 0`, I have the extra check for `Y =\= 0` in the `X > 0` case to avoid cuts, and finally the `Z is -Z1` to compensate for negative `X`.

Note that `times1(-X,Y,Z1)` works without first doing `X1 is -X` because when `-X` is passed to `times1`, `times1` first evaluates `X < 0` or `X > 0` which will evaluate an expression for `X`, so the `-` will be evaluated as desired. Although it still may be safer to first do `X1 is -X` and not make the assumption. So that first clause would become:

```
times1(X, Y, Z) :- X < 0, Y =\= 0, X1 is -X, times1(X1, Y, Z1), Z is -Z1.
```

Testing:

```
| ?- times1(3,5,L).

L = 15 ? a

(1 ms) no
| ?- times1(-3,5,L).

L = -15 ? a

(1 ms) no
| ?- times1(-3,-5,L).

L = 15 ? a

no
| ?- times1(3,-5,L).

L = -15 ? a

no
| ?- times1(3,0,L).

L = 0 ? a

no
| ?- times1(0,0,L).

L = 0 ? a

L = 0

no
| ?- times1(0,5,L).

L = 0 ? a

no
```

Multiplying `0` with `0` shows two solutions since it matches two cases. You can eliminate that with the cuts if you need to as you had in your original solution, or you can adjust the predicate logic such that it enforces non-overlapping cases.

Comment: what does this symbol mean  ' =\= '?

Comment: @Shiran `=\=` checks for numerical inequality of numeric expressions. Since I'm just checking a single variable against a single value (*e.g.*, `Y =\= 0`) I could have also used a "does not unify" check such as `Y \= 0`, but `=\=` is technically correct. Can you check that you entered them correctly and tell me what you tried? I tested the code and it works for me.

Comment: I have posted my second try above the way you have suggested to do it.. I think the syntax is correct..

Comment: @Shiran the results I have added to my answer are using the code I'm showing, so it does work.

Comment: can you run my second code and tell me if it's working for you please ?

Comment: @Shiran I did and it works fine for me. I would like to know why you think it's not working. Perhaps there's a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: @Shiran I get `X = 20`. Double check that you entered the code correctly. What Prolog interpreter are you using? (GNU, SWI, ...)

Comment: @Shiran I ran your query `times1(5,4,X).` in SWI using your code and it worked for me, `X = 20`.